# Have/has sentence usage in the following sentences. Can someone help me with it?

Tags: tense, sentence-structure, singular-vs-plural, causative-have

Does Jules have/has feelings for him?
Does Jules have/has the golden touch?
Does Jules have/has a plan?
Have is plural and has is singular. So technically for the last sentence, I should choose have. But I guess it's wrong but not quite sure. Can someone help me with me. And someone let me know the tense and it's form.

Comment: This 'have' is not plural, it's just the basic form of the verb (which happens to be the same).

Comment: As commented by @KateBunting, 'have' is used here as a main verb. E.g., we can use have as 'do have'; has as 'does have', and had as 'did have', similar to  study = do study; studies = does study, and studied = did study.

Comment: By the way Namita it's is short for it is but its is a possessive form so the last one you use should be its not it's.

Answer (score 1):

When any question begins with do/does, **have** is used all the time. The verb do is associated with the person of the sentence. **Have is independent of it.**

Answer (score 1):

**Do** is an *auxiliary verb* that's used with other verbs to form questions, make things negative, add emphasis etc. The main verb it modifies is always the *infinitive* form:

- *Jules has feelings* - the main verb is *have*, conjugated to *has* (present simple, third-person singular)
- *Jules does not have feelings* - negative form, the auxiliary *do* gets conjugated instead, *have* stays as the infinitive
- *They don't have feelings* - negative again, auxiliary *do* is conjugated differently (third-person plural) to match the subject. *Have* stays in the infinitive
- *Jules **did** have a plan* - emphasis, auxiliary *do* is conjugated as appropriate (now we're talking about the past), *have* stays in the infinitive form.
- *Do you have the answer?* - question form, *have* is still infinitive, hopefully you get the idea now!

Auxiliary verbs are "helper" verbs that add some sense to a main verb - *do* **can** be used as an auxiliary, but it can be used as a normal verb too, e.g. *she did a good job*. The main auxiliary verbs are *do*, *be* and *have*, and they're used like this:

- *do + infinitive*
- *have + past participle* (e.g. perfect forms, *I have been to France*)
- *be + past participle* (passive form, *I was contacted*)
- *be + present participle (-ing)* (continuous form, *I am swimming*)